# How stop Listening to firebase location in android

Tags: android, firebase

How can I stop the listening to firebase location in Android.

I have tried using `firebaseObj.onDisconnect().cancel();`, but no luck.

Answer (score 18):

There is a method called `removeEventListener` that you can call to remove a specific event listener.

You need to pass in the listener that you wish to remove, which you can get in one of two ways:

1. when you already have a reference to your listener

   ```
   ref.addValueEventListener(myLoggingListener);
   ...
   ref.removeEventListener(myLoggingListener);
   ```
2. if you create the listener inline:

   ```
   var listener = ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                      // implementation of the onDataChange and onCanceled
                  });
   ...
   ref.removeEventListener(listener);
   ```

Note that this is explained in [Firebase's Android guide in the section on retrieving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching).

Comment: Actually i implemented ChildEventListener again to removeEventListener. Now i passed same reference of ChildEventListener which i used for addChildEventListener. It worked, thanks alot :).

Comment: I have chat app with 100+ friends and i have created 100+ childs and listened to that , So when that user logouts i need to remove all the listener once how to do that do i need to use a loop?

Comment: From the guide you can also use addListenerForSingleValueEvent to listen for only a single value event.

Comment: Just making it more clear. In the second case, The Data type should be ValueEventListener instead of var. Like this--> ValueEventListener listener = ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   // implementation of the onDataChange and onCanceled
               });

Comment: What difference does this make? In terms of performance or efficiency?

Comment: Perfect, answer,,,:)