# Detaching multiple callbacks at once in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

```
   // Group node listener were all the user group messages arriving
    public void listenToGroupNode() {
        Log.i("FireBase", "listenToGroupNode");
        try {
            final List<UserGroups> dataFromDataBase = new UserGroupsActions(dbHelper).getAllUserGroups();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataFromDataBase.size(); i++) {
                final String groupId = dataFromDataBase.get(i).getId();
                if (!listenedUserGroups.contains(groupId)) {
                    listenedUserGroups.add(groupId);
                    try {
                        Firebase mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIRE_BASE_URL).child(Constants.CHAT_TYPE_GROUP + File.separator + groupId);
                        childEventListeners.add(mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                                ChatData chatData = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
                                if (!messagesActions.isMessageAvailable(chatData.getMessageId()))
                                    handleReceivedMessage(groupId, chatData);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                handleRemovedMessage(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                            }
                        }));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The above method i wrote to listen to a number of groups in a user have in a chat application the user may can have more than 100 groups and i used for loop to listen to each node by creating the callbacks inline and this works fine now i want to remove all these listener when user clicks logout,how can i do this

Comment: Means i should keep all the firebase reference and callback reference when ever i need to remove them

Comment: No am keeping the listener, also going to keep corresponding FireBase reference too to remove them when i wish to ,Thanks Frank Van, And is there any way to check whether a listener completely removed if else i may get messages after i logout also :(

Comment: Cleaning up comments, since I wrote them up into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already keep a list of the listeners:

```
childEventListeners.add(mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {....
```

You can remove all of them by looping through them and calling [`removeEventListener()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Query.html#removeEventListener-com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener-) for each.

Also see this question: [How stop Listening to firebase location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378446/how-stop-listening-to-firebase-location-in-android)

The Firebase servers will stop sending messages when you've unregistered the listener. There *might* be some lingering events in the client, but that's a very small number and usually not worth caring about.

If you want to care and guarantee that you handle no more events when the user logs out, you can keep your own boolean `isLoggedIn` and `if (isLoggedIn)` in the events.