# Firebase is Calling onChildAdded twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I am calling `OnChildAdded` method inside SearchTextView OnQueryListener which searches and Display Records in Dialog using `OnChildAdded` method. But when I run the code the `OnChildAdded` method seems to call inner code twice as the dialog Prompt twice and  same for Log Statements too.

Here is the Code of the method:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
  mSearchQuery = query.trim();              
  mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("name").startAt(mSearchQuery).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        student = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        EnrollOperationFragment enrollOperationFragment =  EnrollOperationFragment.newInstance(student.getName(),student.getId());
        enrollOperationFragment.show(fragmentManager,ENROLL_OPERATION);}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onChildAdded` will be called for each child node matching your query. But also note that you're adding a new child listener each time the user submits the search text. So if they submit twice, you have two listeners and your `onChildAdded` will get called twice for each child (once for each listener). Then when they submit a search again, it'll add a third listener. And so on.

The solution is to detach the previous listener before attaching a new one. See the [documentation for detaching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners). Or use the code from her for inspiration: [How stop Listening to firebase location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378446/how-stop-listening-to-firebase-location-in-android)

Comment: Tried your  solution @Frank van Puffelen but got no luck,Firebase Listener only returns  twice not more than that, Here is the code to detach listener: if (dataSnapshot !=null){ student = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class); Log.d("check",student.getName()); mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(this);} }

Comment: `this` makes no sense in that last call. In the second link I provide, you can see how to keep a reference to the listener and then use that reference to unregister.